# anugular 6 subscribe to subject from multiple component at a same time not working

Tags: angular, subject-observer

I have two components(parent and child) and one service which are subscribed to a subject class at the same time. But when then subject class emit data using `next` method, only one component (child) is getting the data.

navbar.component.ts :(sender):

```
this.messageService.setClientUserAuth(this.respObject.details.actionDtls);
```

message.service.ts: (subscriber)

```
constructor(private route: Router, private _rest: RestApiService) {
  this.getClientUserAuth().subscribe(auth => {
    console.log('AUTH :' + JSON.stringify(auth));
  });
}
setClientUserAuth(id: any) {
   this.clientUserAuth.next(id);
}

getClientUserAuth(): Observable<any> {
   this.clientUserAuth = new Subject<any>();
   return this.clientUserAuth.asObservable();
}
```

base-template.component.ts : (Subscriber) (child )

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.messageService.getClientUserAuth().subscribe(auth => {
    console.log('------------>' + JSON.stringify(auth));
  });
}
```

action.component.ts (Subscriber)(Parent)

```
constructor(private _rest: RestApiService, private messageService: MessageService,
          private route: Router, private modalService: NgbModal, notifier: NotifierService) {
this.messageService.getClientUserAuth().subscribe(auth => {
  console.log('----::----->' + JSON.stringify(auth));
});
}
```

When the data comes from  navbar component ,only base template `subscription` function got the data,But if I delete the `subscription` method from base template , then `subscription` method from action component get it. But I want the data inside all the components and services at a same time as they all are rendered at same time.How to achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your service method, remove initialization of subject from the method "getClientUserAuth()", initialize your observable where you are defining it (also may be you want to make it private):

```
private _clientUserAuth = new Subject<any>();
getClientUserAuth(): Observable<any> {
   return this._clientUserAuth.asObservable();
}

setClientUserAuth(id: any) {
   this._clientUserAuth.next(id);
}
```

Every time any component, calls a subscribe over the return of `getClientUserAuth()`, you were ending up creating a new subject.